# How do I roll loot for monsters that can only drop specific types of loot?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, treasure

For example, grimlocks drop standard coins, standard goods (gems only), and standard items.
What does it mean by "(gems only)"?
So far my guess is that I roll normally, but if the result is some art, then there's neither art NOR gems to be found.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. I'm adding the D&D 3.5 tag to your question; if you meant something else by "3.5," please [edit] it so the tags reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

> Parenthetical Notes
>
> Some entries for goods or items include notes that limit the types of
>   treasure a creature collects.
>
> When a note includes the word “no,” it means the creature does not
>   collect or cannot keep that thing. If a random roll generates such a
>   result, treat the result as “none” instead.
>
> When a note includes the word “only,” the creature goes out of its way
>   to collect treasure of the indicated type. **Treat all results from that
>   column as the indicated type of treasure.**
>
> It’s sometimes necessary to reroll until the right sort of item
>   appears.

Normally you would roll d100 to see what type of goods you have found. Instead of that, you only roll for the number of gems, and a d100 for every gem to determine what kind of gem it is.

For example:

A grimlock with 4 levels of warrior will roll a d100 to determine the number of coins and another d100 for items. For gems you will only roll a d4, because the CR is 5.

[All treasure rules and tables.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/treasure.htm)